# After running a flutter project this error message appears. flutter pub get also shows an error too shown below

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ffi

***flutter pub get* shows the error:**

/Users/sony/development/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in bedrive-flutter...
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:

! device_info_plus 8.2.2 (10.0.1 available)

! ffi 2.1.2

Running "flutter pub get" in bedrive-flutter...                     5.6s
Process finished with exit code 0

**And running the app on android causes this error below:**

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/ffi.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.18.
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file

^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/allocation.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.18.
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file

^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/allocation.dart:48:1: Error: Can't have modifier 'final' here.
Try removing 'final'.

final class MallocAllocator implements Allocator {
^^^^^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/allocation.dart:134:1: Error: Can't have modifier 'final' here.
Try removing 'final'.

final class CallocAllocator implements Allocator {
^^^^^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/arena.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.18.
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file

^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf8.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.18.
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file

^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf8.dart:16:1: Error: Can't have modifier 'final' here.
Try removing 'final'.
final class Utf8 extends Opaque {}

^^^^^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 2.18.
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file

^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:1: Error: Can't have modifier 'final' here.
Try removing 'final'.
final class Utf16 extends Opaque {}

^^^^^
../../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:59:31: Error: The operator '+' isn't defined for the class 'Pointer'.

- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'Uint16' is from 'dart:ffi'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '+' operator.
  final char = (codeUnits + i).value;
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/sony/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/sony/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: is it new project , if not when this issue started ? also share flutter env details

Answer (score 0):

consider updating packages to latest along with flutter